# postgres update parent if entity / foreign key updates

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a table `recipes` and every `recipe` can have multiple `entries`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "recipes" (
    "ident" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "identifier" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "modified_on" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "entries" (
    "ident" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "recipe_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT
    FOREIGN KEY ("recipe_id") REFERENCES "recipes"("ident") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now when a `recipe` is updated, the following function is called and updates my timestamp:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_recipe_timestamp_proc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW."modified_on" = now();
    PERFORM pg_notify('notify_recipes_update', CAST(NEW.ident AS text));
    RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Now I also want my timestamp *modified_on* to get updated whenever an `entry` is updated.

The following `trigger` is not working.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_recipes_timestamp_e ON entries;
CREATE TRIGGER update_recipes_timestamp_e BEFORE UPDATE ON entries FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_recipe_timestamp_proc();
```

**ERROR: Record "NEW" has no field "modified_on"**

Comment: Your trigger is on `entries`, but that table has no field named `modified_on`. Are you trying to update `modified_on` on the `recipes` table instead?

Comment: Exactly! Whenever an entry is updated, the Timestamp of the recipe should get updated.

Comment: `NEW` refers to the new record inserted/updated in the table that you have created the trigger on - in this case that is `entries` and not `recipes`. You can add an `UPDATE` to the `recipes` table in its place to achieve what you want.

Comment: What do you mean with *add an UPDATE to the recipes table*? Make an own function with an `UPDATE` statement which is called by the entry?

Comment: Replace your `NEW.`... line with an update statement. Like, `UPDATE recipes SET modified_on = now() WHERE ident = NEW.recipe_id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stated this in the comments, but I'll place it here for completeness.

Your current issue is that you are trying to set the value of a field that does not exist. `NEW` in a trigger is the actual record that you are inserting or updating AND because that is occurring on the `entries` table. Based on that, you can see why they would not work and why you are getting that error.

The solution to your issue is to remove that line `NEW."modified_on" = now();` and instead replace it with an `UPDATE` statement that will update the `recipe` table.

Your final trigger code should look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_recipe_timestamp_proc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE recipe SET modified_on = now() WHERE ident = NOW.recipe_id;
    PERFORM pg_notify('notify_recipes_update', CAST(NEW.ident AS text));
    RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

The record you are inserting/updating in `entries` has the field `recipe_id` which you use in the `UPDATE` statement to ensure you are updating the correct record in the `recipe` table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have the solution, for this reason I had your comment upvoted.